# using nuget package for android application ore unity to get sqlite worked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sqlite

is it Allowed to tune my Android-Game with Nuget package (sqlite, from microsoft, in VS) to develop for Android? Ore is there copieright on it becouse it should be only Allowed to develop for RT.
I dont need trouble, and want do learn c# in the same way.
And this would be real great and a reason why, i have learn CS to develop at a later time, for RT-Tablets.

I see right now.
1- System.Data.SQLite.Core
2- System.Data.SQLite.Linq
3- Entity Framework (6.1)
4- System.Data.SQLite.EF6

if it is Allowed, and if it is working like i think, maybee somebody show example here.
Else write me becouse it dos'nt work.

If it works and Allowed, i turn back to stackoverflow and show my commandline/Logs/ ore quik komment how i get it done.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With unity seens like the answer is this

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html

And it is Allowed

Answer (score 0):

my ide, is to write db with unity and use it with my main-language, java (with unity development). the second intension, is: if i, write android apps with c# (video lesson from Keith Welch, where ndk, v-studio, sqlite-package,  must install) to hand over, into java code.
so my finally question: is it possible, to use java code, in c# android development, with v-studio, ore write sql-db with unity, into android-installation-package-directory (data/data/..so, on)from android application, which is installed on phone,at runntime?

quik side note: paying sqlite in unity assets-store, is to ignore.